# android - loading json in expandable list view with scroll

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, uitableview

i have an application that download's and save the Json database to Storage .

i should to view the Json objects in Expandable List View and i have a lot of theme so i must have  a scroller too !

i want to know how to parse the Json and load it in array , then use the array for making the Expandable List View ?

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(gURL);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/H3S/DB";
        File file = new File(PATH);
        String fileName = fName;
        File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
```

and this is sample json response : (sorry the json language is persian and the titles won't be shown because of they are not UTF-8) :

```
{
"DBVersion":"4" , 
"Groups":[
{
    "Id"    : 1,
    "title" : "Ú©Ø§Ù…Ù¾ÛŒÙˆØªØ±",
    "bg"    : "1.png"
},
{
    "Id"    : 2,
    "title" : "Ø´ÛŒÙ…ÛŒ",
    "bg"    : "2.png"
},
{
    "Id"    : 3,
    "title" : "Ø¨Ø±Ù‚ Ùˆ Ø§Ù„Ú©ØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÛŒÚ©",
    "bg"    : "3.png"
},
{
    "Id"    : 4,
    "title" : "ÙÛŒØ²ÛŒÚ©",
    "bg"    : "4.png"
},
{
    "Id"    : 5,
    "title" : "Ø±ÛŒØ§Ø¶ÛŒ",
    "bg"    : "5.png"
},
{
    "Id"    : 6,
    "title" : "Ù…Ú©Ø§Ù†ÛŒÚ© Ùˆ Ù‡ÙˆØ§ÙØ¶Ø§",
    "bg"    : "6.png"
},
{
    "Id"    : 7,
    "title" : "Ø²ÛŒØ³Øª",
    "bg"    : "7.png"
}
]
}
```

im an iOS Developer and i successfully do this in iOS with Grouped Style UITableView but i don't know how can i do this simply in android !

Comment: can you please  add your json response ,so i can give you solution.

Comment: @Suraj I'm updated the question see it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you. This is code for parsing the response.

```
  try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                    String Dbversion= jsonObject.getString("DBVersion");
                    JSONArray jaGroups = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Groups");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jaGroups.length(); i++) {


                        JSONObject jsObject = jaGroups.getJSONObject(i);
                        String Id = jsObject.getString("Id");
                        String title = jsObject.getString("title");
                        String bg = jsObject.getString("bg");

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: in iOS i just made simple NSObject for each object in JSonarray how can i make a custom object (class) that contains ID , title , bg in android ?

Comment: you have to create one class,in that you have to declare three String variable i.e id, title,bg for that you have to write (genrate) getter and setter method for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JsonReader` in android on an `InputStreamReader` . You just have to adapt the parsing in the developer example to your needs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html